# Vanilla JS - SetAttribute to All Elements

Tags: javascript

I need help to populate the text from each element of *span* and *em* into Attribute for each elements.

**Expected Results**
[image]

```js
var spanTxt = document.querySelector("div a span").textContent;
var emTxt = document.querySelector("div a em").textContent;
var divAll = document.querySelectorAll("section a");

for(var i=0; i<divAll.length; i++){
    divAll[i].setAttribute("list-span", spanTxt);
    divAll[i].setAttribute("list-em", emTxt);
}
```

```html
<section>
<div><a href="#">Line <span>Test 1</span> <em>One</em></a></div>
<div><a href="#">Line <span>Test 2</span> <em>Two</em></a></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const linksArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section a')); // we use Array.from to transform the NodeList from querySelectorAll to an array. Needs to IE11

linksArray.forEach(linkEl => { // we search for every span and em inside the link
 linkEl.setAttribute("list-span", linkEl.querySelector('span').textContent);
 linkEl.setAttribute("list-em", linkEl.querySelector('em').textContent);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7v3womnt/

Comment: Thanks Salmen, code simple and the result as expected.